# Convert numbers to time in R

Tags: r

I wanted to convert data frame column with numbers to hours (in numbers), for example if the value is 75, I need to convert it to 1.15 or if the value is 180 I need to have it converted to 3 and so on. need not necessarily be in time format. I am aware that below function is user to convert number to time , but what I am trying to do is different.

```
x = c('834', '1534')    
time <- substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", x), format='%H%M'), 12, 16)
```

a

Comment: So you want to convert minutes into hours, is that it? What's wrong with `as.numeric(x) / 60`?

Comment: @AndreElrico I'm assuming it's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a number of seconds (such as 75) to a decimal format such as `minutes.seconds` is a bit odd, but you could do it this way:

```
a <- 75
hour <- floor(a / 60) # floor() rounds down to the last full hour
minute <- a %% 60 * 0.01 # the %% operator gives you the remainder in base 60
new_time <- hour + minute

1.15
```

Comment: to make it a real solution: `x = c('834', '1534', '75', '180');

convert_M2H <- function(x) {
    a <- as.numeric(x);
    hour <- floor(a / 60);
    minute <- a %% 60 * 0.01;
    new_time <- hour + minute;
};

sapply(x,convert_M2H);`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you're after a simple minutes to (fractional) hours conversion.

**Note that there seems to be a mistake where '75' should in fact be 1.25 instead of 1.15. If this is not a mistake, please explain how '75' becomes 1.15.**

```
x = c('834', '1534', '180', '75')

as.numeric(x) / 60
#[1] 13.90000 25.56667  3.00000  1.25000
```

Comment: Hi Maurits, what I am looking for is time conversion of a numeric value 75 (in minutes)  to hours, 75 minutes is 1 hours and 15 mins, hence I need an output of 1.15 minutes and not 1.25, method suggested by @jbobres did the job.. thanks

Comment: @Vikram That's an *extremely* unconventional definition of fractional hours. *Commonly* the fraction denotes a *decimal* fraction, not a *sexagesimal* fraction. If you want to denote 1 hour and 15 minutes, you would write this as `1h15m`, **never as `1.15`**.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function, it works although is not the best approach.

```
number.to.time <- function(x){  
hours <- as.numeric(x)/60  
clean.hours <- floor(hours)  
minutes.60 <- clean.hours*60  
get.extra.minutes <- as.numeric(x) - minutes.60  
result <- paste(clean.hours, get.extra.minutes, sep=".")  
return(result)  
}
```

**Result;**

```
>number.to.time(75)
[1] "1.15"

>number.to.time(1112)
 [1] "18.32"

 x = c(75, 190, 200, 1155)

> number.to.time(x)
[1] "1.15"  "3.10"  "3.40"  "19.15"
```

Comment: 1. input type of x is string (OP), 2. `200 -> 3.20`, not `3.40`, 3. use `return()` not `print()` in function.

Comment: Hi JM_44, this function is very helpful

Comment: Thanks @AndreElrico